# Xcode 4 - Documentation: How to show the Table of Contents?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

simple question, but after jumping over to the new XCode 4 IDE and open the organizer and select the "Documentation", i can´t find a way how to display the "table of contents" of a visible class..

I think about a way how to display it before and the current web-documentation:
Hope someone can answer it.. Thanks

[image: table of contents]

Comment: Appears to be gone from xcode 4.  The plan seems to be to dumb down the IDE so children can write apps.

Comment: Without hacking Xcode, it seems the new way is to use the top bar which contains the TOC of the current page. Also Rightclick+Open page in browser does the trick. These answers were suggested below by rla46 and Gottfried

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo egrep -lRZ "Prototype.Browser.Xcode4OrNewer=Prototype.Browser.XcodeVersion<1000;" /Library/Developer/Documentation/DocSets | xargs -0 -L % sudo sed -i '' -e 's/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=Prototype\.Browser\.XcodeVersion\<1000\;/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=false\;/g'
```

It will fix up some of the javascript that disables the ToC in Xcode 4. Make a backup of your developer DocSets if you like.

Comment: And here is command if you didn't make a backup and don't like the result: `sudo egrep -lRZ "Prototype.Browser.Xcode4OrNewer=false;" /Library/Developer/Documentation/DocSets | xargs -0 -L % sudo sed -i '' -e 's/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=false\;/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=Prototype\.Browser\.XcodeVersion\<1000\;/g'`

Comment: Note I'm using the command posted by coolio for xcode 4.3 in Terminal. However it is not working. I get an error "File name too long" message and the command does nothing. Can you tell how to fix this?

Comment: 10.8.2 and newer seem to be problematic here, no idea what's going on.

I got around the "File name too long" issue by going to the "~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets" folder and using

`sudo egrep -lRZ "Prototype.Browser.Xcode4OrNewer=Prototype.Browser.XcodeVersion<1000;" . | xargs -0 -L % sudo sed -i '' -e 's/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=Prototype\.Browser\.XcodeVersion\<1000\;/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=false\;/g'`

Comment: I also ran into another with one js file that could not be changed by sed, had to edit it manually, or it stopped the whole process.
I'll Update my original reply.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried Ingredients? http://fileability.net/ingredients/ I know it's not exactly what you want, but quite a good solution for viewing the documentation.

Comment: Oh, cool! Thanks for that link. I´ve just installed it. I will check it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you click on the document name (NSString Class Reference in this case) in the bar above the documentation area that Caleb refers to, that document's Table of Contents is available with the right arrow.

Answer (score 2):

In XCode 4.2 Robert's fix needs a little change because the doc set path changed to /Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets:

```
sudo egrep -lRZ "Prototype.Browser.Xcode4OrNewer=Prototype.Browser.XcodeVersion<1000;" /Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets | xargs -0 -L % sudo sed -i '' -e 's/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=Prototype\.Browser\.XcodeVersion\<1000\;/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=false\;/g'
```

UPDATE: And for XCode 4.3 which installs as an App Store App the location moves to the user library:

```
 sudo egrep -lRZ "Prototype.Browser.Xcode4OrNewer=Prototype.Browser.XcodeVersion<1000;" ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets | xargs -0 -L % sudo sed -i '' -e 's/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=Prototype\.Browser\.XcodeVersion\<1000\;/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=false\;/g'
```

UPDATE 2/2013. With OSX 10.8.2 and newer I ran into two more issues, one is the one mentioned by regulus6633: Some files bail with a comment that the file name is too long.
I solved it by switching to the docs folder (~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets) and using a shortened command

```
 sudo egrep -lRZ "Prototype.Browser.Xcode4OrNewer=Prototype.Browser.XcodeVersion<1000;" . | xargs -0 -L % sudo sed -i '' -e 's/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=Prototype\.Browser\.XcodeVersion\<1000\;/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=false\;/g'
```

The second problem was that I had one file blocking the process because it could not be changed. No idea, as to why, permissions looked OK (was reported as nonexistant which was obviously wrong).
I ran out of patience and fixed it by changing that one file manually.

There's another change in XCode 4.6, here the command for the new docsets needs to be (from the docset folder)
You might still need to run the old one, too, if you newly install legacy docsets

```
 sudo egrep -lRZ "Prototype.Browser.Xcode4OrNewer=Prototype.Browser.XcodeVersion<1e3;" . | xargs -0 -L % sudo sed -i '' -e 's/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=Prototype\.Browser\.XcodeVersion\<1e3\;/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=false\;/g'
```

Another Update, May 2013:
I can no longer get the egrep command to work with the iOS 6.1 sources and OSX 10.8.3, I switched to manually changing the devpubs.js file (it's actually the only one that needs changing) in  ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets//Contents/Resources/Documents/Resources/yresource number>/JavaScript and the change you need to make is to reset the "Xcode4OrNewer=Prototype.Browser.XcodeVersion<1e3,..." term to "Xcode4OrNewer=false,..."

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the page and and select "Reveal in Library".

The corresponding documentation node will be opened. This is the same subtree as we see in the browser, but displayed along with other articles.

Answer (score 1):

you can right click the page and select "Open Page In Browser"

Comment: Thanks for your help. But unfortunately it opens only the webpage (ex. UIView) but no "table of contents". So it doens´t help ;(

Comment: that's odd, for me it will then open the page in my browser including the table of contents. I'm using Firefox though, so that could be a difference.

Comment: Thanks, i´m using safari. So like you said, that could it be. Though, i would like the table of contents within the IDE back!!!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the only way I think is to use the browser. Ingredients http://fileability.net/ingredients/ is a nice tool (in my opinion the best of the ones currently available) but doesn't show the table of contents either.

Answer (score 1):

I kept ending up in this page when looking for a way to, by default, HIDE the TOC in the Xcode 4 documentation. Here's my solution:
as I only use SnowLeopard documentation, I ended up modifying only the file at

/Library/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleSnowLeopard.CoreReference.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Resources/585/JavaScript/header_toc.js

```
if(Cookie.get("toc-visible")==="false"){TOC.hide()}else{TOC.show()}
```

to

```
if(Cookie.get("toc-visible")==="false"){TOC.hide()}else{TOC.hide()}
```

So, to SHOW it by default, just put {TOC.show()}else{TOC.show()} in the header_toc.js files in your docsets.